# Windows Error Reporting service connection failure

Tags: windows-7, windows-error-reporting

For some reason unknown to me, the Windows Error Reporting service has now decided that it cannot send crash reports to Microsoft.

[image]

I get the above error when I try to "Check for a solution" from Review Problem Reports Dialog.  "Trying again later" does not work.  I've tried several recommended "fixes" including scanning for corrupted system files, making sure the WER service is running, and, checking firewall issues.  Sending crash reports used to work, so, I'm at a loss as to why this is happening. Can anyone shed some light on a possible cause?

Comment: According to the error message box, just *some* reports could not be uploaded. What are the reported problems? Have you got a `C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP` file?

Comment: @and31415 All of the problems listed in the Review Problem Reports dialog are present in the WER ReportQueue folder.  The actual crashes are application errors (c0000005) that I initiated.  I have a dump file, but, I'm trying to ensure that these get reported to Microsoft.

Comment: Where's the dump file stored, and what's the file size?

Comment: @and31415 The dump is stored in the ReportQueue folder (eg. \AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue) and is 166mb.

Comment: Is that the `ReportQueue` folder total size? Reported problems should correspond to a small `Report.wer` file. What happens if you try to report just one problem at a time? Open a command prompt and run this command: `nslookup watson.microsoft.com` Then post here the output. Do you get the same issue if you [perform a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us)?

Comment: @and31415 I've already tried a clean boot and running in safe mode.  The size quoted was for one dump file.  The current ReportQueue size is 738mb.  As requested, here's the output from the nslookup...  **Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\nnn>nslookup watson.microsoft.com
Server:  r2d2.mycompany.com
Address:  172.xx.xxx.5

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    watson.microsoft.com.nsatc.net
Address:  157.56.141.102
Aliases:  watson.microsoft.com**

Comment: You didn't say so, so I had to ask. Are you behind a proxy? Also, are you able to report *single* problems? Try using [Bad App](http://www.ntwind.com/software/utilities/badapp.html) and make it crash on purpose, then try to send the report.

Comment: @and31415 I've had our network guy check all of that.  It's got to be something specific to my pc since other programmers don't have this problem.